# How to determine behaviour of this derivative in the following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following differential equation $$\frac {dx}{dt} = ax + \cos(x)$$

for some $a \in \mathbb R$. I need to determine the shape of the direction field of $x(t)$ in the vertical axis and $t$ in the horizontal axis as $a$ increases from $-0.1$ to $0.1$. The suggestion that the problem (as stated in the book) gives is to look at the graphs of $ax$ and $\cos(x)$.

I could sketch the fields for several values of $a$ but I don't know if this what the problem is asking for. I am looking to comprehend how to use the graphs of $ax$ and $\cos(x)$ to see the behaviour of the derivative and then for a hint on how to approach it.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant. I was able to determine that the number of critical points increases in $-0.1 \le a < 0$, is infinite at $a = 0$, and starts to decrease in $0 < a \le 0.1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "slope field" defined by a differential equation of the form $$\dot x=f(x)\tag{1}$$ in the $(t,x)$-plane is horizontally invariant: All "infinitesimal curve elements" on a horizontal line $x={\rm const.}$ have the same slope. It therefore suffices to draw these curve elements on the $x$-axis, i.e. on the vertical axis $t=0$. The slope of the curve element at $(0,x)$ is given by the value $f(x)$, and may change its sign at points $(0,x_k)$ where $f(x_k)=0$. When $f(x_k)=0$ the prescribed slope is $=0$, and this means that $x(t)\equiv x_k$ is a solution of $(1)$. In an interval $x_{k-1}<x<x_k$  the sign of the slope is constant, and as different solutions cannot cross it follows that in this strip the solutions behave qualitatively like $\tanh$, or $-\tanh$, depending on the sign of $f(x)$.

For the example at hand we have to look at the graph of $f(x)=ax+\cos x$ for given $a\in[-0.1,0.1]$.  The function $f$ has a finite number of  zeros. For most values of $a$ all of these zeros are simple (i.e.,  $f$ changes sign there), and for some "special" values of $a$ one of the zeros is a double zero, and $f$ does not change sign there.

These explanations should allow you to draw the required figures for various $a$'s in the given interval.

Answer (score 0):

When determining the intersection of $ax$ and $\sin (x)$ it is clear that the value of $a$ affects the number of critical points. In other words, different slopes of the line $ax$ will intersect with $\sin (x)$ at different points. The closest $a$ is to $0$ the bigger the number of intersections that there will be.

By looking at the graph of $\sin (x)$, one can determine that the direction field of the equations will be alternating periodically between pointing "upward" and "downward" for each area that the graph of $x(t)$ against $t$ is divided by because of the critical points.

From here it is straightforward to see the changes in the number of critical points and in the direction field as $a$ increases.